# Asymptotic Bound

Tags: asymptotics, recursion, recursive-algorithms

$$T(n) = \Theta \left ( n^{1/2} \left ( 1 + \int_1^n \frac{1}{u^{3/2}}\ du \right ) \right ) = \Theta \left ( n^{1/2} \right )$$

This asymptotic bound is evaluated to be $n^{1/2}$ but isn't the correct answer $n$ and not $n^{1/2}$?

Just to give some background this is applying Akra and Bazi theorem on divide and conquer recurrence T(n).

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searcahble) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users have an easier time finding this question. In the future, you should do the same ^_^

Comment: The correct bound is $\Theta \left ( n^{1/2} \right )$. Would you mind saying more about why you think it's $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor because the integral = ( u^-(0.5-1) ) / -0.5+1. so at the end you get an expression like this: n^0.5 + (n-n^0.5) / 0.5. n is the dominant term, therefore it is n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have a bit of an issue evaluating the integral.

$$\int_1^n \frac{1}{u^{3/2}} du = -\frac{2}{u^{1/2}} \bigg |_{u=1}^n = 2-\frac{2}{n^{1/2}}$$
Using this we can simplify
$$n^{1/2} \left (1 + \int_{1}^n \frac{1}{u^{3/2}} du \right ) = n^{1/2}\left (3 - \frac{2}{n^{1/2}}\right ) = 3n^{1/2} - 2$$
When written in this form it is clear that the correct order is $\Theta(n^{1/2})$ since
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3n^{1/2} - 2}{n^{1/2}} = 3
$$
which shows that for large enough $n$, the expression is within a constant multiple of $n^{1/2}$.